# Create a CUBESET for date range

Tags: excel

I manage to create two CUBEMEMBERS and now i m trying to create a periodic CUBESET but i m getting an error of `#VALUE!`

**CUBEMEMBES** (Correct values)

- **F2 formula:** `=CUBEMEMBER("Db","[Time Dimension].[Standard Time Hierarchy].[All].["&$I$2&"].["&$J$2&"].["&$K$2&"].["&$L$2&"]")`
- **F3 formula:** `=CUBEMEMBER("Db","[Time Dimension].[Standard Time Hierarchy].[All].["&$I$3&"].["&$J$3&"].["&$K$3&"].["&$L$3&"]")`

**CUBESET** (Error occurred)

- **F5 formula:** `=CUBESET("Db","{["&$F$2:$F$3&"]}")`

**Image:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

`=CUBESET("Db","{[Time Dimension].[Standard Time Hierarchy].[All].["&$I$2&"].["&$J$2&"].["&$K$2&"].["&$L$2&"]:[Time Dimension].[Standard Time Hierarchy].[All].["&$I$3&"].["&$J$3&"].["&$K$3&"].["&$L$3&"]}","Time Cubeset")`